# Javascript div random positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that i'm learning in javascript and i don't know everything yet.
I want to do a div with random position. I found this:

```
(function makeDiv(){
  var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
  var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
  $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px',
    'background-color': color
  });

  var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
  var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

  $newdiv.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left': posx+'px',
    'top': posy+'px',
    'display': 'none'
  }).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100).delay(300).fadeOut(200, function(){
    $(this).remove();
    makeDiv(); 
  }); 
})();
```

and it is what I wanted mainly but not exactly.

I want to modify this code where I have one `<div>` element in body and it's position just changes on mouseover. I have this now: 
http://screenshot.sh/m7WhBlRPAQ7vs
It doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a screenshot is hard to convert to text, could you add the missing HTML as text in your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the bellow js code. Is this you need?
There're two comments to you can understand what is happening

```
<script>
(function makeDiv(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none'
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100); 
    //on the coded above the div shows up


//the code bellow adds the event mouseover to the div
//when fired, makes the div to fadeout and removed, then creates another div
$newdiv.mouseover(function(){
    $newdiv.fadeOut(200).remove()
    makeDiv()
    });
}());
</script>
```

Comment: It works but sometime it can have #5BC6FF or #D4FF9E color. I tryed to fix it by myself but when i did it the code for moving div was no firing, These colors are colors of background and menu on top. <div> can go on to menu but that is not problem for me. If you can fix it i will be very happy. Thanks

Comment: Is there any solution how to make div remove slower or after a period of time?

Comment: Well, about the colors you can use a while statement to control (while color is qual than #5BC6FF or #D4FF9E, random it again.

To make the div to remove slower, you might change the number on fadeOut to a grater number. I'd suggest to you also remove the event of the div right after the mouseover, because the mouseover will trigger anyway while its fadding out. You can remove the event by using .off()

Comment: I understand just first half. I tryied to change fadeout to greater but it seems like there is no change. I saw that it changes  when i delete .remove() than it fades out right with the time. I want to do kind of mini-game when based on when you have mouse on square or rectangle it disapears and you have to click on it but it's impossible when it disappears 0.001s after mouse over. I've got the second part of code. I mean the part with click.

Comment: I tryied http://screenshot.sh/n70hnUx7ZfFcK and the result is nothing code is not running. I tryied to write "makeDiv()"instead of continue and nothing again.

Comment: I found a way to do this. I just deleted ".remove()". There are many divs on page but their display is none so they are not destroying page. And the   ".fadeOut" works correctly. Only problem is with while() when I set it the code is not running at all.

Comment: Gustavo you really did help me! I love you :D. I fixed problem with colors just by changing it to a fixed #24a4b5. Now everything works. If you want to see a code and how i did it just tell me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! I'd appreciate to see that ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Create a div and give it an id="moveMe". This code is in jQuery, easier to learn js logic with.

I added comments so you can see what it is doing.

```
//first we want to get the width of the screen
var width = jQuery(window).width();
//now the height of the screen
var height = jQuery(window).height();

//when the mouse enters our div with an id set to moveMe preform a function
jQuery('#moveMe').mouseenter(function(){
  //randomly select a position on the y axis
  var topPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * height)+0);
  //randomly select a position on the x axis
  var leftPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * width)+0);
  //now move the div. Because we are looking to see if the mouse enters moveMe we can use this here, as the element is already slected.
  jQuery(this).css({position:'absolute', top:topPos+'px', left:leftPos+'px'});
});
```